# Replace Multiple Tables in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I got 1 big Crystal file, that generates letters from our system. We have about 200 different letters, that all have their own section, and depending on the letter code, we suppress all sections but the relevant one.

This report is based on 1 main table, and several other tables/views. This main table is emptied and filled every time a letter is requested by the end user.

Now I have been asked by management to automate this generation process. The problem is, that my main table is empty during the day, and only generated when the end user requests something manual.

I created a new process, where all information is collected in 1 command (alternatively I can fill my own table, so I would have 1 table instead of 20+).

However, I can't just remove all tables and add this command. When we started building this file, we had no knowledge of CR, so a lot of fields are used directly in the report, not in formula's.

I know I can replace 1 table by 1 table at a time. However, that process is useless as I need to replace all tables with this 1.

My question is, is there a way to replace all tables with the 1 new table, without having to rebuild the entire file? This would save me many many hours if it was possible.

Comment: I think you will have to spend many many hours because when you change data source then CR deletes all fields from tables which was removed (in your case 20+) and you will have to add all those fields back (from your new 1 table). It is frustrating but it happens when users don't have enough knowledge about the tool they working with. No offense.

Comment: Non taken. This file was originally build over 3 years ago, when I had 0 knowledge about the tool. I've come quite a bit since then, but am hitting a wall now. Guess management can decide if they want to invest the development time in this then.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly you should be able to set Data source location (drop down menu under database) and change each table one at a time to the new table. A mapping window should appear if field names aren't found exactly and you can map the fields. Repeat with each old table

Comment: I know this is possible, but I want to avoid this. My command is already containing information from all other tables, so I need to remove all tables, and just have this one. But if I remove all tables, all fields in the file get deleted as well

Comment: What I stated above will accomplish that. As you set the Data Source location from each table one at a time to the new table, you will be able to map fields if needed and the old tables will disappear and you will be left with the one table (command).